# How to replace map.resource from our own code on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have developed my project using

```
map.resource :user
```

Now I need to do it manually how can I do this [I mean I need to map user in routes file]?

Comment: I suppose it should be a `map.resource :user`?

Comment: yes that's correct I edited it.

Comment: Why are you moving away from REST actions? Are you trying to add custom routes? Can you give an example?

Comment: Do you want to do this within Rails or without a framework at all?

Comment: I want to do it Within rails framework.

Comment: I have to ask why too. Why? Do you need to do something that it doesn't already do for you?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but I believe the singleton resource maps routes like this:

```
match 'user/new' => 'users#new', :via => :get, :as => :new_user
match 'user' => 'users#create', :via => :post

match 'user/edit' => 'users#edit', :via => :get, :as => :edit_user
match 'user' => 'users#update', :via => :put

match 'user' => 'users#show', :via => :get
match 'user' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete
```